# Window floating utility for Mac

Tags: osx

I would like a utility to float windows on top of other windows. In some programs, this option is called always on top.

Features:

- Ability to activate via keyboard shortcut
- Lightweight - minimal impact on performance
- Runs on OS X Mavericks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AFload](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat) is what you want. As the official website says,

> AFloat will add many window management features to most Mac
> applications: Keep windows afloat (heh) on top of all others. Pin
> windows to the desktop. Move windows from anywhere, not just the title
> bar. Turn a window into an "overlay" on your screen that doesn't hinder
> your work. Show a window's file in the Finder with nothing more than
> your keyboard. Resize windows from anywhere, not just the edges, and
> more.

The available version on their official website says that it works for OS X Lion and Snow Leopard, however the [github version](https://github.com/fjolnir/afloat) is [said](https://superuser.com/a/694185)  to be working fine on Mavericks.

Some of the keyboard shortcuts are:

[image]

And you can learn more about it in detail [here](http://www.technorms.com/9458/enable-top-pin-desktop-overlay-windows-feature-mac).

Comment: The installation is rather complex, but I found the instructions here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113093/how-does-one-install-afloat-on-os-10-8-mountain-lion#

Thanks, Afloat lets me float the terminal, but sadly it only works for Cocoa apps. So I can't float sublime for  exam.

Comment: Ah! That's a shame. I find it so annoying that Mac never decides to include some of the very basic features that Windows has had since V. 95!